# Getting an undefined token in backend

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt

Hello i am trying to use my token in my application after user is logged in but am getting an undefined response in my console. Below are my codes. How can i correct my code to be able to access token inside application and use to do other features of the application?

my controller

```
import User from "../models/user";
import Stripe from "stripe";
const stripe = Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET);
export const createConnectAccount = async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.user);
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id).exec();
    console.log("USER ==> ", user);
    if (!user.stripe_account_id) {
      const account = await stripe.accounts.create({
        type: "express",
      });
      console.log("ACCOUNT ===>", account);
      user.stripe_account_id = account.id;
      user.save();
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json();
  }
};
```

my middleware

```
var { expressjwt: jwt } = require("express-jwt");
// req.user
export const requireSignin = jwt({
    //secret, expiryDate
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    algorithms: ["HS256"],
});
```

my routes

```
import express from "express";

const router = express.Router();

import { requireSignin } from "../middlewares";

import { createConnectAccount } from "../controllers/stripe";

router.post("/create-connect-account", requireSignin, createConnectAccount);

module.exports = router;
```

my auth controller

```
import User from "../models/user";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export const register = async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;

  if (!name) return res.status(400).send("Name is required");
  if (!password || password.length < 6)
    return res
      .status(400)
      .send("Password is required and should be minimum 6 characters long");
  let userExist = await User.findOne({ email }).exec();
  if (userExist) return res.status(400).send("Email is taken");

  const user = new User(req.body);
  try {
    await user.save();
    console.log("User saved successfully", user);
    return res.json({ ok: true });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("CREATE USER FAILED", err);
    return res.status(400).send("Error.Try again");
  }
};

export const login = async (req, res) => {
  // console.log(req.body);
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  try {
    //check if user with credentials
    let user = await User.findOne({ email }).exec();
    // console.log("USER EXISTS", user);
    if (!user) res.status(400).send("User with email not found");
    //compare password
    user.comparePassword(password, (err, match) => {
      console.log("COMPARE PASSWORD IN LOGIN ERR", err);
      if (!match || err) return res.status(400).send("Wrong password");
      //("GENERATE A TOKEN THEN SEND AS RESPONSE TO CLIENT");
      let token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: "7d",
      });
      res.json({
        token,
        user: {
          _id: user._id,
          name: user.name,
          email: user.email,
          createdAt: user.createdAt,
          updatedAt: user.updatedAt,
        },
      });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("LOGIN ERROR", err);
    res.status(400).send("Signin failed");
  }
};
```

my terminal output

```
POST /api/login 200 1142.309 ms - 349
undefined
POST /api/create-connect-account 500 9.092 ms - -
```

Headers

```
import axios from "axios";
export const createConnectAccount = async (token) => {
  await axios.post(
    `${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/create-connect-account`,
    {},
    {
      headers: {
         Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`, 
        },
    }
  );
```

};

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to tell you your code has other errors in it.

My guess is that your res is not well written in auth controller, login function :

```
res.status(201).json({
        token :token,
        user: user
})
```

Also when reading your token trying to authenticate : it will be easier to use the same package than the one that sign it.

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
exports. requireSignin = () => {
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const token = req?.headers?.authorization?.split(" ")[1];
      const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
      const userId = decodedToken._id;
      const user = await User.findOne({ _id: userId });
      if (user) {
        req.auth = {
          user: user,
        };
      } else {
        throw new Error("user not found");
      }
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      res.status(401).json({ error: "failed to authenticate" });
    }
  };
};
```

But your code is pretty hard to read :
To make it easier to read and clearer for you, try and use joy or yup

- Joi : https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi
- Yup : https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup

With those you will be able to create middlewares to avoid wrong entries in your body : for example

```
if (!name) return res.status(400).send("Name is required");
```

is processed automatically with those packages

Also, you shouldn't use 'import' and 'require' in the same project, choose either one of them

I hope this will help

Comment: This doesn't help. I don't know where to indicate the corrections you noted can u kindly help indicate at what point should the corrections be taken

Comment: Let me modify my answer

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
export const currentUser = async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.auth);
    
};
```

`req.user` has been moved to `req.auth`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **JWT** in **node.js** then you may use this on **client** side

```
const data = await response.json();
    if (data.token) {
      

      console.log("Token received:", data.token);
      
      // Store the token in localStorage
      localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
    
      
    } else {
      console.log("Token is undefined or empty in the response data");
    }
```

response (`response.json()`) will be generated by fetching data

And for **server** side

```
 var token = jwt.sign({  userid: user.userid, name: user.name }, 'shhhhh');
    // console.log("token  generated")
    res.status(200).json( {success:  true ,token});
```